# How can I use "renderDataTable" in Shiny?

Tags: shiny, rstudio, dt

I am currently working with `Shiny` in `Rstudio`, I want to display a table in `mainPanel`. 
I create a `data.table` like this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNnTA.png)
When I put this `data.table` in `Shiny` it looks like this:
[Only one letter/number in each cell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHgDE.png)

Here are my codes:

```
ui <- fluidPage(   titlePanel(),   sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(dataTableOutput(outputId = "table"))))


server <- function(input,output){   Name <- c("max","min","mean")  
Value <- c(45,26,35)   dt <- data.table(Name, Value)  
output$table=renderDataTable({dt}) }
```

Is there something wrong with my codes or it is because the setting in `renderDataTable`?

Comment: I am new to stack overflow and not familiar with it. Please click  "1" and " Only one letter/number in each cell." to see the pictures. Thank you.

Comment: Rather use the `DT` package. `library(DT)`, and `DTOutput("table")` and `renderDT({datatable(dt)})`.

Comment: It worked! It is amazing! Thank you! @Stéphane Laurent

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Could you provide some commentary or explanation as to why the `DT` package is a preferable option here? What's wrong with `renderDataTable`?